# How to debug a WPF application with asynchronous data access and no Call Stack?

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, asynchronous, data-access

I have a large WPF application that uses the MVVM design pattern and asynchronous data access methods. It uses the old style asynchronous code with callback handlers and the `IAsyncResult` interface... here is a typical example:

```
function.BeginInvoke(callBackMethod, asyncState);
```

Then , in the view model, I have the following callback handler:

```
private void GotData(GetDataOperationResult<Genres> result)
{
    UiThreadManager.RunOnUiThread((Action)delegate
    {
        if (result.IsSuccess) DoSomething(result.ReturnValue);
        else FeedbackManager.Add(result);
    });
}
```

The `RunOnUiThread` method is basically the following:

```
public object RunOnUiThread(Delegate method)
{
    return Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, method);
}
```

This problem only affects one view model, the one that enables the users to edit the `Release` objects. On the related view, certain collections that populate `ComboBox`es are requested from the database when it is first loaded. Let's simplify this saying that there is just one collection called `Genres`. After the data arrives in the view model, it is handled like so:

```
private void GotGenres(GetDataOperationResult<Genres> result)
{
    UiThreadManager.RunOnUiThread((Action)delegate
    {
        if (result.IsSuccess) Genres.AddEmptyItemBefore(result.ReturnValue);
        else FeedbackManager.Add(result);
    });
}
```

When the collection is present and a `Release` object has been selected in the UI, I have the following code selects the current `Release.Genre` value from the collection:

```
if (!Release.Genre.IsEmpty && Genres.ContainsItemWithId(Release.Genre.Id)) 
    Release.Genre = Genres.GetItemWithId(Release.Genre);
```

At this point, I should note that this all works fine and that this is the *only* line that references the `Release.Genre` property from the view model.

My particular problem is that sometimes the `Release.Genre` property is set to `null` and I can't work out how or from where. >> Edit >> When I put a break point on the property setter, << Edit << the `Call Stack` provides no real clues as to what is setting the `null` value, as there is only a `[Native to Managed Transition]` line. On selecting the `Show External Code` option from the `Call Stack` window, I can see basic asynchronous code calls:

[image: Call Stack]

Now I can confirm the following facts that I have discovered while attempting to fix this problem:

1. The one line that references the `Release.Genre` property is **not** setting it to `null`.
2. The call to Genres.AddEmptyItemBefore(result.ReturnValue) is **not** setting it to `null`... this just adds the result collection into the `Genres` collection after adding an 'empty' `Genre`.
3. The `Release.Genre` property is sometimes set to `null` in or after the call to Genres.AddEmptyItemBefore(result.ReturnValue), but **not** because of it... when stepping through it on a few occasions, execution has jumped (in an unrelated manner) to the break point I set on the `Release.Genre` property setter where the `value` input parameter is `null`, but this does **not** happen each time.
4. It generally happens when coming from a related view model to the `Release` view model, but **not** every time.
5. The related view model has no references to the `Release.Genre` property.

To be clear, I am not asking anyone to debug my problem from the sparse information that I have provided. Neither am I asking for advice on making asynchronous data calls. Instead, I am really trying to find out new ways of proceeding that I have not yet thought of. I understand that some code (almost certainly my code) somewhere is setting the property to `null`... my question is how can I detect where this code is? It does not appear to be in the `Release` view model. How can I continue to debug this problem with no more clues?

Comment: Maybe flat file logging or database logging can help you? Usually I use those 2 logging if cannot debug using VS, especially in WPF since binding less likely debugable.

Comment: I don't think that is caused by any code. You must have a binding to that property somewhere, which should be changed to `OneWay`.

Comment: @Fendy, could you please explain your idea further?
@HighCore, I thought you were onto something then because my the `Binding` to the `Genres` collection on the `ComboBox` did not have `OneWay=True`. Unfortunately, after I added it, I still have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @Sheridan See my answer below

Comment: Instead of trying to step through the code, could you put a conditional break point on the `Release.Genre` setter for when `value == null`? And then check the call stack or step through from there to find the culprit?

Comment: Maybe my text wasn't clear... that is exactly what I have been doing. The `Call Stack` image that I uploaded is from that point. As can be seen from the image, calls from the `PresentationFramework` is setting it to null.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Flat File, XML or Database logging for debugging purpose. I created those Log classes for logging purpose, so that I can call it from every applications I develop.

For database logging, you can do it as simple as:

```
void WriteLog(string log){
  // Your database insert here
}
```

Maybe you need datetime and other supporting information, but it's up to the developer. For simple flat file logging is:

```
void WriteLog(string log){
  using(TextWriter tx = new StreamWriter("./Log/" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".txt", false)){
    tx.WriteLine(log);
  }
}
```

You can use the logging in your application in both ways:

1: Method call

```
WriteLog((Release.Genre == null).ToString());
if (!Release.Genre.IsEmpty && Genres.ContainsItemWithId(Release.Genre.Id)) 
    Release.Genre = Genres.GetItemWithId(Release.Genre);
```

2: Add it in your Release.Genre set (or get) property

```
public class Release{
  private Genre _genre=null;
  public Genre Genre{
    get{
      WriteLog((_genre == null).ToString());
      return _genre;
    }
    set{
      WriteLog((_genre == null).ToString());
      _genre = value;      
    }
  }
}
```

With this, you can try to get the call sequence, whether the Release.Genre is being set in other places before, during call, etc.

Please note I just giving the general image of building logging. Please expect errors. However, it is developer's responsibility to develop the Logging acitivities to meet requirement.

Comment: Thanks for expanding your idea @Fendy. While interesting, I'm not sure how this can help me in this situation. As far as I can tell, this method won't help me to discover what is setting the property to `null`. In fact correct me if I'm wrong, but it doesn't seem as if it could help any more than putting a break point on the setter.

Comment: @Sheridan It is not as easy as breakpoint but this way can do the work. You can log the DateTime and additional information such as method name or variables, in replacement for breakpoint. Do the log at where you will likely put the breakpoint.